# String.replace and String.replaceAll Methods not working for blanks

Tags: java

I have a String, where I need to replace all whitespaces and "and"s with "" or "_". My code however isn't working.

```
    text = "working and travelling";
    text = text.replaceAll("and","_");
    text = text.trim();
    text = text.replace(" ","");
    text = text.replaceAll(" ", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\t", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

The output produced is "working _ travelling"

I found the solution. Thank you for your help. There was a non-break space, that I couldn't see. So the working method was

```
    text = text.replaceAll("\\x0B","");
```

Comment: So the desired output is "working_traveling"? What are you getting with the current code?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't produce that output, at least, not if you're outputting `text`. You should describe your expected and actual output.

Comment: So two spaces remain. `text = text.replace("\u00a0", "");` for a non-breaking space came to mind. But that seems not to be the case. Is the code shown correct?  You edited somewhat (missing semicolon).

Comment: Thank you, indeed there was a non-breaking space, that I couldn't see. The text was read from an excel file, that's why I edited. So the method, that worked, I used text = text.replaceAll("\\x0B","");

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String text = "working and travelling";
        text = text.replaceAll("and","_").replaceAll(" ","");

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Output is "working_travelling"

Answer (score 0):

To replace `"and"` by an underscore, `replace("and", "_")`.
To delete a vertical tab character, `replace("\\x0B","")`.
To delete any whitespace, `replaceAll("\\s", "")`.

```
text = text.replace("and", "_").replace("\\x0B","").replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

You only need `replaceAll` if you're using a regular expression. The regular expression `\\s` matches any whitespace character.